# "The import com.cinterion.io cannot be resolved" error

Tags: java, jar, at-command

I am working on a java application and need to import "com.cinterion" to utilize ATCommands. I am using TC65i-terminal. How can i find the cinterion jar files to resolve the mentioned error?

Comment: I want to help, even if this question is probably not suitable for this site (you are asking for an external resource)...

Comment: First of all, "Cinterion" is the old name of the [Gemalto](https://developer.gemalto.com/) company. I found [this thread](https://developer.gemalto.com/threads/problems-comcinterionio) showing that what you need is [cwm_lib_1.0.jar](https://developer.gemalto.com/documentation/cwmlib10jar). It in turns is included in the custom [SDK](https://developer.gemalto.com/threads/sdk-availablility); bad news is that it doesn't seem to be a public resource, but something you can access after registering through a sales distributor.As you can see,it is really difficult to build a good answer out of this..

Comment: @RobertoCaboni Yes you are right about the name. But the modem i am using is rather old, Thanks anyway;

Comment: I hope that my links can be a good start to find what you need.